# Create a t-test and obtain p-value from csv using shiny

Tags: r, shiny, bioinformatics

I am trying to create a shiny UI to input CSV, perform paired t-test (equal variance) and to generate a heatmap from a sample dataset.

I have been able to generate a UI CSV upload tab, however, I am now struggling with my t-test and p-value tab, I continue to get this error message:

> Warning: Error in : evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
>     90:

```
   shinyServer <- function(input, output, session){

  data5<- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    data5<-read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                   header = input$header,
                   sep = input$sep,
                   quote = input$quote)
  })

   output$contents <- renderTable({

      req(input$file1)
    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(data5()))
    }
    else {
      return(data5())
    }

  })

   ####ttests
   data1 <- reactive({
     data1 <- data.matrix(data5())
   })
   ctrl <- reactive({
     ctrl <- data1()[, c(2:11)]
   })
   smple <- reactive({
     smple <- data1()[, c(12:21)]
   })

   vector1 <- c(1:10)

   pvalue <- c()
   pval <- reactive ({
     for (i in vector1) {
       pvalue[i] <-
         t.test(ctrl()[i, ],
                smple()[i, ],
                paired = FALSE,
                var.equal = FALSE)$p.value

     }
     pvalue
   })

   signif <- reactive({
     sig <- c()
     for (n in vector1) {
       if (pval()[n] < 0.05) {
         sig <- append(sig, n)
       }
     }
     sig
   })

   genecol <- reactive({
     genecol <- data5()[, 1]
   })
   P.Vals <- reactive({
     as.character(P.Vals())
   })

   data6 <- reactive({
     data6 < -data.frame(genecol(), P.Vals())
   })

   output$pvalue <- renderTable(data6())

}
```

UI:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
ui <- fluidPage(
  ####name app
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Upload CSV"),

    # Sidebar
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        ###input option CSV file
        fileInput(
          "file1",
          "Choose CSV File",
          multiple = TRUE,
          accept = c("text/csv",
                     "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                     ".csv")
        ),


        tags$hr(),

        ###check if CSV has a header
        checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

        ###format text file into table with separator (comma,semicolon,tab)
        radioButtons(
          "sep",
          "Separator",
          choices = c(
            Comma = ",",
            Semicolon = ";",
            Tab = "\t"
          ),
          selected = ","
        ),


        tags$hr(),

        ####select head of data or all
        radioButtons(
          "disp",
          "Display",
          choices = c(Head = "head",
                      All = "all"),
          selected = "head"
        )

      ),

      ####output panel
      mainPanel(# Output: DATA
        tableOutput("contents"))
    )
  ),


  tabPanel("T-Test",
           h4("pvalue"),
           tableOutput("pvalue"))

)
```

I understand this may be complicated but I am a complete beginner, really struggling to get my head round it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Can you include the code you have and point out which bit is giving the error?

Comment: @RAB apologies for the long code and disorganisation, I'm struggling to understand as it is but I have added my code and willing to clarify more clearly if needs be

Answer (score 1):

Without a reproducible example (see the comments), I am guessing it could be your reactives. I.e.:

```
data1 <- reactive({
     data1 <- data.matrix(data5())
   })
```

A reactive is kinda like a function, as it returns the last value (or whatever is passed with a return statement). In your code, you seem to be reassigning the reactive `data1` with a value, within it self. This might not be the case due to scoping, but with the recursive error, this is my first guess.

I suggest you start with editing your reactives to:

```
data1 <- reactive({
   data.matrix(data5())
})
```

**EDIT:**

Found it:

```
   P.Vals <- reactive({
     as.character(P.Vals())
   })
```

This is most definitely a recursive expression. This is your culprit.

Comment: I've changed my code a little and now my waarning message is Warning: Error in dframe: could not find function "dframe"

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot help you with "dframe" - I cannot see your updated code. Could it be you simply misspelled "data.frame"?